THD of cascode emitter follower
I read an article about how the linearity of an emitter follower can be improved using a cascode configuration.
Here is the article: https://www.passlabs.com/technical_article/cascode-amp-design/ 
For the following explanation I am referring to the 3 circuits I have attached below. 

circuit 1 (non cascode for comparison): 
 

circuit 2: 
 

circuit 3: 
 

In short, the emitter of the emitter follower is connected to the base of the cascode transistor Q3. That way the emitter of Q3 follows the emitter of Q1. This holds the voltage between emitter and collector of Q1 constant, and therefor nonlinearities of the output characteristics of Q1 should disappear since the Vce is always constant.
I tried to build and simulate this configuration, comparing it with a non cascode emitter follower. In the simulation (done with LTSpice) circuit 1 has an THD of: 0.0041%, circuit 2 has: 0.0061%, and circuit 3 has: 0.0042%
Surprisingly the cascode hasn’t improved the THD. In circuit 2 the THD is worsened. I assume that is because the output is loaded additionally by the R9 // R10. That’s why I designed circuit 3 that has almost no additional loading since the current source Q4. I get similar results when building and measuring the circuits.
So circuit 3 gives me about the same performance than the simple emitter follower in circuit 1. Why is there no improvement in THD as describe in the article?

You are using a push-pull circuit that doesn't appear in the article so why would you expect an improvement?

It’s not push-pull. The lower transistor Q2 is a constant current source to set the bias current for the emitter follower.

You are missing my point.

@Andyaka It doesn't look push-pull to me :) Easy mistake to make though.

And you are also missing my point but appear to understand my point when you made your answer.


Why is there no improvement in THD as describe in the article?

Because you have not built the circuit in the article :)
The article is about power amplifiers where there's say 0.5A or more of collector current, and old power transistors are used (late 1960s tech I bet), with their notoriously low beta and so-so linearity.
Instead, you're trying it with a high-beta small-signal part operating right where it should in terms of idle current. It's pretty good all by itself as you've shown.
Now try it in a power amplifier, as described in the article. You can buy 2N5878, a TO-3 package part, from Central Semiconductor. They still have them in stock, although they stopped making them and for a good reason - there's no need to use those parts in any new designs.
But even if you try it with some other medium or high power transistors, you'll see the improvement. Just make sure you're operating between 0.5A to 5A of collector current, since that's roughly the regime Pass is talking about.

Thank you so much for that answer!
I know that the amplifier described in the article was a power amplifier and used more nonlinear transistors. However, I thought that there would also be an improvement with modern transistors in low-power applications.

BC547 came, IIRC, about a decade-and-a-half after 2N5878. The pace of BJT development back then was such that it could be a night-and-day difference. But also remember that SPICE transistor models may not capture all nonlinearities. If you actually care about nonlinearity, you need to be able to measure it in a real circuit. You may be surprised at what you find. So I still highly suggest that you try it for real!!

I have built circuit 1 and 3 to measure the THD using my audio analyzer. It's 0.0046% in circuit 1 and 0.0047% in circuit 3 at 1kHz and 2Vp input. So also, the real test confirms the result. The Transistors are just too good by themself to see an improvement.
